# adding previous array values to newer array values

Tags: php

```
$test = 'test1/test2/test3/test4';
```

I am trying to get a array from that `$test` above which i'd like to output like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => /
    [1] => /test1/
    [2] => /test1/test2/
    [3] => /test1/test2/test3/
    [4] => /test1/test2/test3/test4/
)
```

I've tried loops but can't quite figure out how to get it quite right.

Comment: Which language is that? Please retag if I was wrong, but there was no statement about it in the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try to make loop like :

```
$test = 'test1/test2/test3/test4';
$test_arr = explode("/", $test);
$test_size = count($test_arr);
$count = 1;
$new_test_arr = array('/');
for ($i=0; $i<$test_size; $i++)
{
  $new_test_arr[$count] = $new_test_arr[$i] . $test_arr[$i] . "/"
  $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy and simple way, for this case would be

```
$test = 'test1/test2/test3/test4';
$arr = explode("/", $test);

$t = "";
$newArray = array("/");
foreach($arr as $value) {
   $t .= "/".$value;
   $newArray[] = $t;
}

print_r($newArray);
```

#### [Demo](http://ideone.com/yxP6J)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it very compactly:

```
$parts = explode("/", $test);
for($i = 0; $i <= count($parts); ++$i) {
    echo "/".implode("/", array_slice($parts, 0, $i))."\n";
}
```

Not terribly efficient, but I don't think efficiency would matter in something trivial you 'd only do once. On the plus side, the loop modifies no variables which makes it easier to reason about.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/H9jJ3)**.